# Get the absolute path to checked-out files in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I have a Java Github repo with build hooks into Jenkins that runs tests when pull requests are submitted.
We also have a subdirectory that contains a bunch of JSON config files. I want to write a test that ensures that all the files in this subdirectory is valid JSON.

Is there a way to get the location of the source code directory when its downloaded in jenkins?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jenkins populates a WORKSPACE environment variable that supplies the path where the files were checked out.